# UIKeyboard height different after device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, rotation, uikeyboard

I have the problem that after the device rotation the keyboard height:

```
guard let keyboardSize = sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
```

is different to the normal value. Normal keyboard height (on tested device) is 398 and after the rotation the height is 142.

More context:

I write an iPad only app which has a view which always should stick to the center (Y) even the keyboard is shown. For this case I have the center Y constraint as outlet. I registered my ViewController for the `UIKeyboardWillShow` and `UIKeyboardWillHide` notifications. When the hide notification is called I set the constraint constant to 0. When the show notification is called I calculate the new center Y depending on the remaining view space (`view.height - keyboard.height`).

When the `UIKeyboardWillShow` is called for the first time everything is working fine. But after I rotate the device the keyboard height is different and my calculation gives me a wrong value.

How can I correctly calculate the center Y after the rotation with a keyboard displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Farhan Arshad is right that UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey will give you better results, but it doesn't solve the problem you mentioned.

When you register for UIKeyboardWillShow (or UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame for that matter), you actually get multiple notifications when you rotate the from portrait to landscape. The first notification has the keyboard with height 142 pixels and the second notification has it with 398 pixels. Use the second notification for your constraint value and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Good practice is to add/remove observers:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }


override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

**This is the key to solve your issue**
Try reading `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

`@objc` required for Swift4

```
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo? 
      [UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

                //Your code here

      }
    }
```

Comment: While UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey is the proper piece to use to get keyboardSize under normal circumstances, it does not solve the problem.